# SQLite - Using LIKE operator on multiple values

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

Is there a way to apply `LIKE` operator on multiple values. 
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val LIKE ('%xyz%' OR '%abc%')
```

Comment: What is the issue in writing SELECT * FROM table WHERE val LIKE '%xyz%' OR val like '%abc%'

Comment: I have a long list of values to look for. It will span across multiple lines and therefore looking a shorthand.

Comment: What you are looking for is not a valid syntax, you need to write explicitly when using LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the code with a CTE that returns all the values that you want to match:

```
WITH cte(val) AS (VALUES ('abc'), ('def'), ('ghi'))
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.val LIKE '%' || c.val || '%'
```

If you get duplicate rows with the above query, use DISTINCT:

```
WITH cte(val) AS (VALUES ('abc'), ('def'), ('ghi'))
SELECT DISTINCT t.* 
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.val LIKE '%' || c.val || '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

From [release 3.36.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_36_0.html) onwards you can use [REGEXP](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

In this case it would be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val REGEXP '.*(xyz|abc).*'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put multiple filters:

```sql
select
  *
from table

where 1==1
and (    val like '%xyz%'
      or val like '%abc%' )
```

Comment: 1==1? Is this a joke of an answer?

Comment: @Mecanik it is not a joke, although 1==1 plays no role (it is a trick to put each filter in a separate `and` block, in other words it is for "readability")